# Bluetooth mouse does not reconnect

Tags: 14.04, 18.04, mouse, bluetooth, bluez

I have a Microsoft Wedge Touch Mouse that I can connect to both an Ubuntu 14.04 and an Ubuntu 18.04 systems. When the 14.04 system resets, wakes up or powers on, the mouse will reconnect automatically.

That is not the case with the 18.04 system. I have to put the mouse in pairing mode to get it to reconnect to the 18.08 system each time the 18.04 system resets, wakes up, or powers on.

Ubuntu 14.04 has the following installed

```
bluez/trusty-updates,trusty-security,now 4.101-0ubuntu13.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
bluez-alsa/trusty-updates,trusty-security,now 4.101-0ubuntu13.3 amd64 [installed]
bluez-cups/trusty-updates,trusty-security,now 4.101-0ubuntu13.3 amd64 [installed]
gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0/trusty-updates,now 3.8.2.1-0ubuntu4.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gnome-bluetooth/trusty-updates,now 3.8.2.1-0ubuntu4.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
indicator-bluetooth/trusty,now 0.0.6+14.04.20140207-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libbluetooth3/trusty-updates,trusty-security,now 4.101-0ubuntu13.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgnome-bluetooth11/trusty-updates,now 3.8.2.1-0ubuntu4.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth/trusty-updates,now 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 amd64 [installed]
```

The 18.04 system has the following installed:

```
bluez/bionic,now 5.50-0ubuntu0ppa1 amd64 [installed]
bluez-cups/bionic,now 5.50-0ubuntu0ppa1 amd64 [installed]
bluez-obexd/bionic,now 5.50-0ubuntu0ppa1 amd64 [installed]
gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0/bionic,now 3.28.0-2 amd64 [installed]
gnome-bluetooth/bionic,now 3.28.0-2 amd64 [installed]
libbluetooth3/bionic,now 5.50-0ubuntu0ppa1 amd64 [installed]
libgnome-bluetooth13/bionic,now 3.28.0-2 amd64 [installed]
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth/bionic-updates,now 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.1 amd64 [installed]
```

Is this some sort of regression bug?

Thanks!

Mark